# Free monoid in the "rank $\omega$" case?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I have a complete and co-complete monoidal category in which the tensor product commutes to filtered colimit in each variables, and I would like to understand the "free monoid" construction in this category.

One knows, for example by the [work](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869374900957) of E.Dubuc, that this always exists, but his constructions has some problems in the $\omega$ case and always require an induction process up to a uncountable regular cardinal, even in the $\omega$ case.

I was wondering if one can come up with a construction that only require a countable transfinite construction.

There is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1946.pdf) of S.Lack which gives a nice answer in the case where the tensor product commutes to reflexive co-equalizer and countable composition. His construction does not seem to be what I'm looking for (in the situation I'm concerned reflexive co-equalizer are not conserved in general and are very messy to compute).

But in the introduction of his paper (linked above) S.Lack mention that in the case of a tensor product which preserve filtered co-limit one can use a formula of the form:

$I + X \otimes (I+X \otimes (I+ X \otimes (...$

He does not give much explanation for this, he seem to imply that this comes from the paper of Kelly on transfinite construction, but I can't find it in the paper, and I haven't been able to figure out the details by myself.

Does someone know what is this construction he is talking about ? Is there other "countable" construction of the free monoid that you know of ?

Comment: The construction only works if we assume that the monoidal category is locally presentable. If it is locally $\lambda$-presentable, and the tensor product preserves $\lambda$-directed colimits, then the transfinite construction needs $\lambda$ steps. Please let me know if you need more details. It might also be a good idea to contact Steve directly.